# How do I set spinning ProgressBar to Media?

Tags: android, button, progress-bar, media-player

I'm creating a soundboard application. Im new to developing but I have my whole app running perfectly exept for one last thing. I have it so I have multiple buttons and each button plays a different sound. I want to have a spinning progressbar on my button while the sound is playing, but then dissappear when the sound is done. How would I do this easily?

Answer (score 0):

so i'm not sure how you're playing your sounds, whether its just one line of code that actually PLAYS the sound. In my opinion, you have two options

If your method returns something once the sound stops playing, I'd do something like

```
while (myapp.playSound() != -1){ //implement spin bar }
```

Or you can use AsyncTask -- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

AsyncTask would probably be your best bet

Answer (score 0):

Add a [OnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) to the mediaplayer, so when you play the sound (or click the button) start the progress bar, and when the track is complete remove/stop it.